# need help reading plist file in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist

I have been trying read data from a plist file. this is how it is structured

```
|term|detail(string)|
```

my properties :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *terms;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *termKeys;//this is just a array to keep track
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detail;
```

this is how I access the detail in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSString *currentTermsName = [termKeys objectAtIndex :[indexPath row]];
                                  [[cell textLabel] setText:currentTermsName];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


    detail = [terms objectForKey:[termKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSLog(@" bombs %@",terms[@"Bomb Threats"]);
    return cell;

}
```

and in view didload I have

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                            pathForResource:@"terms" ofType:@"plist"];
        terms = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
        termKeys = [terms allKeys];
    }
```

It accesses the values , but it store the same one for each object
lets say I have 5 different records in plist, if i print detail it displays the same record 5 times.

```
Once detail is set then I pass it to detialView
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailsegue"]){
        TermsDetailViewController *controller = (TermsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.detailTerm = detail;
    }
}
```

Here is my dictionary :
http://pastebin.com/bxAjJzHp

Comment: what do you mean "it store the same one for each object"?

Comment: lets say I have 5 different records in plist, if i print `detail` it displays the same record 5 times

Comment: I guess you should use this: `detail = [ [ terms objectForKey:@"termKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] ] objectForKey:@"detail" ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not keep a property for detail as it will keep on changing as you scroll the tableView and the code is written in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Try implementing the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ 

      //Path of plist from bundle
      NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistFil" ofType:@"plist"];

     //Since your plist's root is a dictionary else you should form NSArray from contents of plist
      self.terms = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

      self.termKeys = [self.terms allKeys];

      [self.tableView reloadData];

     //As you have a key for "Bomb Threats" in your plist,try logging if it successfully initialized with values of plist
      NSLog("%@",terms[@"Bomb Threats"]);
}



 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsForSection:(NSInteger)section{
       return [self.termkeys count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     //Initialize cell

     NSString *key   = self.termKeys[indexPath.row];
     NSString *value = self.terms[key];

     cell.textLabel.text = key;
     cell.detailTextLabel.text = value;

     return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

//Try using this if segues are coming straight from cells

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailsegue"])
    {
        TermsDetailViewController *controller = (TermsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [ self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSString *key   = self.termKeys[indexPath.row];
        self.detail = self.terms[key];
        controller.detailTerm = self.detail;
    }
}
```

Comment: `NSLog("@ %@",terms[@"Bomb Threats"]);` prints the right text but passing `value` to `detail` gives me the same problem

Comment: Can you show the implementation of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Here you are setting the value of details to a property details. It will only contain the value of last stored value in it. Where are you making use of the value stored in self.detail?

Comment: I pass it to a segue for a detailViewcontroller

Comment: +1 this is close, please lemme know how I should proceed so I could accept your question

Comment: @meda if you want to pass the details to "DetailsViewController", make sure you assign the value to "self.detail" in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. That's it :)

Comment: I have edited my answer. If it works as you expect you can probably accept it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do,

```
 NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSDictionary *terms = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];
 NSLog(@"%@", [terms objectForKey:@"term1"]);
```

in your code,
if

```
termKeys = [terms allKeys];
```

then this should return correct value,

```
detail = [terms objectForKey:[termKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: I dont have objectforkey@"term1" how do I add it ?

Comment: that is just an example, you should use your term names. didn't you try printing out your dictionary? Plz print it NSLog(@"%@", terms); then post the output here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

NSString *strPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        strPath = [strPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary  *terms = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:strPath];
NSArray *arrTemp =[terms allKeys];
arrTemp = [arrTemp sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSString *detail = [terms objectForKey:[termKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.textLabel.text = detail;

return cell;
}
```